# How to get current URL outside views function in django

Tags: python, django, django-cache

I want to get the current url outside the view function so that I can have restriction to use a decorator at a specific URL

```
@cache_page(CACHE_TTL)
def patients(request):
    baseContext = BaseContext(header="Dieter")
    return baseContext.render(request, "patients/patients.html")
```

Now I want to use this "@cache_page" decorator when URL is "https://example.com" 
How can I to that?

Comment: You want to cache all the pages right, like if /abc => get_page_from_cache('abc')

Comment: Yes, and i have implemented that but it is a add on service on herokuapp that is supported only there only, so whenever I run this project in local, it gives a error! So i want to use this decorator only when I am running on heroku

Comment: Do you want to disable cache on a specific `path` or domain?
If you use your app on multiple domains, do you use Site framework ?

Comment: Different domain. No I am not using Site framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can add cache config in local or production settings file accordingly, like following -

```
#local_config.py
#https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/

CACHES = {
  'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
      'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
  }
}
```

And similarly in prod config,

```
#prod_config.py
CACHES = {
  'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'mypackage.backends.whatever.WhateverCache',
      'LOCATION': 'redis://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx',
      'TIMEOUT': None,
   },
}
```

So instead of accessing(using) your prod cache service for local, you could use any other cache like FileBasedCache.

Comment: This seems a right solution for sure! But currently I have seperated the production config, so is there any way I can do it with same config?

Comment: Yes, you can but you would have to write the logic there itself, like if env=PROD: cache={}